# What is this name/reading?

Tags: names, reading

could someone help with the reading of the text in the photo please. Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should ask the calligrapher, maybe this is “Xing Shu”?
The top looks like a "穴" and the bottom looks like a "秀"